# How to Figure Odds?

Tags: probability

My book says:

the **probability** of an event A is given by the formula

[probability formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhJvo.png)

where f is the number of favorable outcomes and n is the number of possible outcomes.

Then, the fair betting **odds** that an event A will happen is given by the formula

**odds(A) = f:u**

where f is the number of favorable outcomes, and u is the number of unfavorable outcomes.

Next, they illustrate with playing cards:

Probability of drawing a face card  = 12/52 = 3/13

Odds of drawing a face card = 12:40 = 3:10

Then they ask:

**If the standard odds are 8 to 5 that the Chargers will beat the Lions, what is the probability that this event will happen?**

Here's where I get lost.  Wouldn't that be 1/13, or 0.0769?  The answer **provided** is 8/13, or .615.

If we follow the illustration for playing cards…

**Probability** of drawing a face card  = 12/52 = 3/13

**Odds** of drawing a face card = 12:40 = 3:10

…we can see that the ODDS of drawing a face card are 12:40.

Now, 12 + 40 = 52.  So, we can glean from this that the odds ADDED together give us the total number of event opportunities?

Thus, if the odds are 8 to 5 that the Chargers will beat the Lions, then the total number of games in a season is 8 + 5 = 13.  Assuming they’re talking about just this one game - then the probability is 1/13? :D

What am I missing?

Comment: Probability is Favorable outcomes over Total outcomes. Not one divided by total outcomes. Does that help?

Comment: Hi!  I'm still confused.  If probability is favorable outcomes over total outcomes - how is it possible for the favorable outcomes to be 8?  Seems like there's just one game?

Comment: You want $$\frac{8}{8 + 5}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing yourself by thinking about it being just one game.  Favorable/Total only applies when each event is equally likely.  If the probability of an event is $\frac ac$ and the probability it does not happen in $\frac bc$ we must have $\frac ac+\frac bc=1$ or $a+b=c$.  We can quote the probability that the event happens or we can quote the odds which are $a:b$.  Here we are told the odds are $8:5$, so the denominator is $8+5=13$ and the probability it happens is $\frac 8{13}$

Comment: I wonder if I'm not conflating "Betting" odds here with just the idea of odds.  I'll post another question with illustrations to try to clarify.